# View TCP header fields from C program running on Debian

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I've successfully made an "echo client", and I'd like to add robustness before moving along to the rest of my project. Notably I'd like to view the "TCP window size" value inside the TCP header, and ensure that I don't flood the server with my next transmission.

I am not sure if this is possible without using raw sockets and forming/parsing the TCP header myself. While that isn't impossible, I'd prefer to use built in functions to access the header with my current code if possible. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

```
#include "../include/a8gcc.hpp"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define buffer_len 512
/* server address */
#define SERVER "192.168.2.115"
/* server port number */
#define SERVPORT 10001


 int main(void)
{ 

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    int sock_fd, num_read = 0;
    char in_data[buffer_len];

    printf("is_ethernet from GCC");
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);

    sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(sock_fd < 0){
        perror("Opening socket error");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        printf("Opening the socket...OK.\n");
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server = gethostbyname(SERVER);
    if(server == NULL){
        printf("%s \n", h_errno);
        perror("getting host address error");
        exit(1);
    }
     bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
             (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
             server->h_length);

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVPORT);

    if (connect(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        perror("ERROR connecting");
        exit(1);
    }


    while(1){
        num_read = read(sock_fd,in_data,buffer_len);
        write(sock_fd,in_data,num_read);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You won't flood the server with your next transmission in any case; one of the functions of the TCP layer is to make sure that doesn't happen.  So I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: I am interfacing a connection to a serial-to-ethernet device, and ovbiously the serial stream can write much slower than the Ethernet stream. The manufacturer has set up the device to report the remaining serial buffer size in the TCP window size, so I'd really like to get that data back to my program to make sure I am not overwhelming their device.

Comment: Right, the TCP layer will handle that issue automatically.  In particular, all the serial-to-ethernet-device's software has to do is not call recv() unless/until there is some room available in its serial buffer.  As long as it does that (which it presumably does), the TCP layer handles the rest -- in particular, their TCP stack will tell your TCP stack to slow down, which will in turn cause your write() call not to return for a while longer.  It's handled for you by TCP, so you don't need to code your own special logic to handle this issue (unlike, say, if yo were using UDP, where you would).

Comment: You're spot on, I just sent a 22MB at the ethernet port of a serial-to-ethernet device, and while the transfer took a while, the TCP layer took care of the window sizing, no intervening on my end! Thank you for helping me realize this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that it is possible for you to examine the actual content of the TCP/IP headers from within your code unless you are going to use raw sockets and generate the packets yourself. :(  Sorry!